# Is eating 400g chicken fillet per day healthy?

Tags: food-safety, healthy-cooking

I do bodybuilding and don't use any drug or supplement. I have three usual meals with my family but I eat about 400g of chicken fillet between usual meals. Is it healthy or eating chicken fillet everyday could be dangerous for health?

Comment: A person who was really advising you would take into account your health, your weight and other such questions, like how much protein are you getting in the three regular meals. So the answer is:  it depends. So as currently worded this would involve personal advice we can’t give.

Comment: I think food/nutrition questions are not allowed, though there may be exceptions if there is a serious medical impact.  I’m not sure.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions about nutrition are off topic here unless they're directly related to medical care. Requests for personal medical advice are also off topic.

Comment: [Are you on this diet?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YdLZ1VRgOmg)